# Split String sequentially every possible split

Tags: python

I'm struggling with ideas for this python script:

I have a string of characters, say `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`

I need to split these into a list, with 7 characters each, resulting in a list that has

```
[abcdefg], [bcdefgh], [cdefghi], ... , [tuvwxyz]
```

as elements.

I have this method, but it currently outputs

```
['abcdefg', 'hijklmn', 'opqrstu', 'vwxyz']
```

...

```
def chunksOf7(toSplit):
    chunks = [toSplit[i:i+7] for i in range(0, len(toSplit), 7)]
    print(chunks)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `chunks = [toSplit[i:i+7] for i in range(0, len(toSplit)-6)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the output lists to shift only one character each. So instead of iterating the `range(len(toSplit)-6)` in steps of 7, it should use steps of 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to iterate over slices of the string of length 7.

```
>>> s = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> [s[i:i+7] for i in range(len(s)-6)]
['abcdefg', 'bcdefgh', 'cdefghi', 'defghij', 'efghijk', 'fghijkl', 'ghijklm', 'hijklmn', 'ijklmno', 'jklmnop', 'klmnopq', 'lmnopqr', 'mnopqrs', 'nopqrst', 'opqrstu', 'pqrstuv', 'qrstuvw', 'rstuvwx', 'stuvwxy', 'tuvwxyz']
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way:

```
>>> import string
>>> to_split = string.ascii_lowercase
>>> [to_split[i:i+7] for i in range(0, len(to_split)-6)]
['abcdefg', 'bcdefgh', 'cdefghi', 'defghij', 'efghijk', 'fghijkl', 'ghijklm', 'hijklmn', 'ijklmno', 'jklmnop', 'klmnopq', 'lmnopqr', 'mnopqrs', 'nopqrst', 'opqrstu', 'pqrstuv', 'qrstuvw', 'rstuvwx', 'stuvwxy', 'tuvwxyz']
```

As a function:

```
def chunksOf7(to_split):
    return [
        to_split[i:i+7]
        for i in range(0, len(to_split)-6)]
```

Comment: see the expected output all the strings should have length 7